# How to move the end a javascript range to a sentence in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

on a javascript [range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) object, IE provides a [`moveEnd`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljgskaax.php) method that can move the end of a range a given number of sentence units.

How can this be accomplished in Chrome?

Here is my code which kinda works, but as you can see, it also highlights past the end of the sentence.

```js
var range = document.getSelection().rangeCount > 0 ? document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0) : new Range();
var startNode = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
var endNode = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
var endOffset = endNode.childNodes.length;
range.setStart(startNode, 0);
for (i = 0; i <= endNode.childNodes.length; i++) {
  range.setEnd(endNode, i);
  if (/.+\./.test(range.toString()))
    break;
}
var newNode = document.createElement("span");
newNode.setAttribute('class', 'highlight');
range.surroundContents(newNode);
```

```css
.highlight {
  
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<p><b>John Fitzgerald</b> "<b>Jack</b>" <b>Kennedy</b> (May 29, 1917 – November 22, 1963), commonly referred to by his initials <b>JFK</b>, was an American politician who served as the <a href="/wiki/List_of_Presidents_of_the_United_States" title="List of Presidents of the United States">35th President of the United States</a> from January 1961 until <a href="/wiki/Assassination_of_John_F._Kennedy" title="Assassination of John F. Kennedy">his assassination</a> in November 1963. The <a href="/wiki/Cuban_Missile_Crisis" title="Cuban Missile Crisis">Cuban Missile Crisis</a>, <a href="/wiki/The_Bay_of_Pigs_Invasion" class="mw-redirect" title="The Bay of Pigs Invasion">The Bay of Pigs Invasion</a>, the <a href="/wiki/Partial_Nuclear_Test_Ban_Treaty" title="Partial Nuclear Test Ban Treaty">Nuclear Test Ban Treaty</a>, the establishment of the <a href="/wiki/Peace_Corps" title="Peace Corps">Peace Corps</a>, developments in the <a href="/wiki/Space_Race" title="Space Race">Space Race</a>, the building of the <a href="/wiki/Berlin_Wall" title="Berlin Wall">Berlin Wall</a>, the <a href="/wiki/Trade_Expansion_Act" title="Trade Expansion Act">Trade Expansion Act</a> to lower tariffs, and the <a href="/wiki/African-American_Civil_Rights_Movement_(1955%E2%80%931968)" class="mw-redirect" title="African-American Civil Rights Movement (1955–1968)">Civil Rights Movement</a> all took place during his presidency. A member of the <a href="/wiki/Democratic_Party_(United_States)" title="Democratic Party (United States)">Democratic Party</a>, his <a href="/wiki/New_Frontier" title="New Frontier">New Frontier</a> domestic program was largely enacted as a memorial to him after his death.</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my answer. Works pretty good.

```js
WebPageReader.Sentence = class extends Range {
  /*  Sentence understance everything about sentences
      It has a starting and ending character, and ends with a sentence terminator
      It can navigate itself around the page
  */

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.dom = new WebPageReader.Dom();
    this.regex = new WebPageReader.Regex();
    this.highlighted = false;
    this.backupHtml = '';
    this.dom.LoadAllTextNodes();
    this.AlignToRange(this.dom.GetSelectedRange() || this.dom.GetFirstRange())
    this.collapse(true);
    this.AlignEndPoints();
    this.Expand();
  }

  /* public properties */
  get CanPrevious() {
    return !this.StartCharacter.Bof;
  }

  get CanNext() {
    return !this.EndCharacter.Eof;
  }

  set Highlighted(value) {
    if (value == this.highlighted) return;
    if (value)
      this.Highlight();
    else
      this.Unhighlight();
    this.highlighted = value;
  }

  /* public methods */
  Expand() {
    this.StartCharacter.Search(this.regex.SentenceTerminator, false);
    this.StartCharacter.Search(this.regex.NonWhitespace, true);
    this.EndCharacter.Search(this.regex.SentenceTerminator, true);
    this.Align();
  }

  Next() {
    this.EndCharacter.Next();
    this.Align();
    this.collapse(false); // collapse to end
    this.AlignEndPoints();
    this.Expand();
  }

  Previous() {
    this.StartCharacter.Search(this.regex.SentenceTerminator, false);
    this.StartCharacter.Previous();
    this.Align();
    this.collapse(true); // collapse to start
    this.AlignEndPoints();
    this.Expand();
  }

  Align() {
    this.setStart(this.StartCharacter.TextNode, this.StartCharacter.Offset);
    this.setEnd(this.EndCharacter.TextNode, this.EndCharacter.Offset);
  }

  AlignToRange(range) {
    this.setStart(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
    this.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
  }

  AlignEndPoints() {
    this.StartCharacter = new WebPageReader.Character(this.dom, this);
    this.EndCharacter = new WebPageReader.Character(this.dom, this);
  }

  Highlight() {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(this);
    this.highlighted = true;
  }

  Unhighlight() {
    this.highlighted = false;
  }

  ScrollToMiddle() {
    var el = $(this.startContainer.parentElement);
    var elOffset = el.offset().top;
    var elHeight = el.height();
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var documentHeight = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
    var offset;

    if (elHeight < windowHeight) {
      offset = elOffset - ((windowHeight / 4) - (elHeight / 2));
    }
    else {
      offset = elOffset;
    }
    window.scrollTo(0, offset);
  }

  Visualize(label) {
    const BeginRangeMarker = '\u25BA';
    const EndRangeMarker = '\u25C4';
    const TextNodeBoundary = '\u2551';
    const NewLineIndicator = '\u21B5';
    var allTextNodes = this.dom.AllTextNodes;
    var msg = '';
    var intersects = false;
    for (var t = 0; t < allTextNodes.length; t++) {
      var textNode = allTextNodes[t];
      var value = textNode.nodeValue.replace(/[\n]/g, NewLineIndicator);
      if (this.intersectsNode(textNode)) {
        if (!intersects) {
          if (!allTextNodes[t + 1] || !this.intersectsNode(allTextNodes[t + 1]))
            // I begin and finish inside this first node
            msg += `${TextNodeBoundary}${value.substring(0, this.startOffset)}${BeginRangeMarker}${value.substring(this.startOffset, this.endOffset)}${EndRangeMarker}${value.substring(this.endOffset)}`;
          else
            // I only begin inside this first node
            msg += `${TextNodeBoundary}${value.substring(0, this.startOffset)}${BeginRangeMarker}${value.substring(this.startOffset)}`;
        } else if (!allTextNodes[t + 1] || !this.intersectsNode(allTextNodes[t + 1]))
          // I end in this node
          msg += `${TextNodeBoundary}${value.substring(0, this.endOffset)}${EndRangeMarker}${value.substring(this.endOffset)}`;
        else
          // I completely contain this node
          msg += `${TextNodeBoundary}${value}`;

        intersects = true;
      } else if (intersects) {
        break;
      }
    }
    // txtVisualization.value = `${msg}║`; 
    msg = `${label} = ${msg}║`;
    console.log(msg);
  }
}

/* Classes */
WebPageReader.Character = class {
  /*  the textual surface of a web page is completely tiled over with text nodes
      a character has the text node on which it sits and the character position (Offset) within that node's text
  */
  constructor(dom, range) {
    this.dom = dom;
    this.TextNode = range.startContainer;
    this.Offset = range.startOffset;
    this.Bof = false;
    this.Eof = false;
  }

  Search(regex, forward) {
    var found = false;
    var buffer = '';
    do {
      if (forward) {
        buffer += this.toString();
        found = regex.test(buffer);
        regex.lastIndex = 0;
        if (!this.Next()) return false;
      } else {
        if (!this.Previous()) return false;
        buffer = this.toString() + buffer;
        found = regex.test(buffer);
        regex.lastIndex = 0;
      }
    } while (!found);
    // roll it one character (get off the match)    
    if (forward) this.Previous();
    else this.Next();
    return true; // found it
  }

  Previous() {
    this.Bof = false;
    this.Offset--;
    if (this.Offset < 0) {
      if (!this.dom.getPreviousTextNode(this.TextNode)) {
        this.Bof = true;
        this.Offset = 0;
        return false;
      }
      this.TextNode = this.dom.getPreviousTextNode(this.TextNode);
      this.Offset = this.TextNode.nodeValue.length - 1;
    }
    return true;
  }

  Next() {
    this.Eof = false;
    this.Offset++;
    if (this.Offset > this.TextNode.nodeValue.length - 1) {
      if (!this.dom.getNextTextNode(this.TextNode)) {
        this.Eof = true;
        this.Offset = this.TextNode.nodeValue.length - 1;
        return false;
      }
      this.TextNode = this.dom.getNextTextNode(this.TextNode);
      this.Offset = 0;
    }
    return true;
  }

  toString() {
    return this.TextNode.nodeValue.substring(this.Offset, this.Offset + 1);
  }
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
  outline: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="prevSentence();" value="Previous" />
<input type="button" onclick="nextSentence();" value="Next" />
<input type="button" onclick="getSelectionRange();" value="Get Selection" />
<input type="text" id="sentenceIndex" />
<input type="text" id="sentence" />
<div>
  <p><b>John Fitzgerald</b> "<b>Jack</b>" <b>Kennedy</b> (May 29, 1917 – November 22, 1963), commonly referred to by his initials <b>JFK</b>, was an American politician who served as the <a href="/wiki/List_of_Presidents_of_the_United_States" title="List of Presidents of the United States">35th President of the United States</a> from
    January 1961 until <a href="/wiki/Assassination_of_John_F._Kennedy" title="Assassination of John F. Kennedy">his assassination</a> in November 1963. The <a href="/wiki/Cuban_Missile_Crisis" title="Cuban Missile Crisis">Cuban Missile Crisis</a>, <a href="/wiki/The_Bay_of_Pigs_Invasion"
    class="mw-redirect" title="The Bay of Pigs Invasion">The Bay of Pigs Invasion</a>, the <a href="/wiki/Partial_Nuclear_Test_Ban_Treaty" title="Partial Nuclear Test Ban Treaty">Nuclear Test Ban Treaty</a>, the establishment of the <a href="/wiki/Peace_Corps"
    title="Peace Corps">Peace Corps</a>, developments in the <a href="/wiki/Space_Race" title="Space Race">Space Race</a>, the building of the <a href="/wiki/Berlin_Wall" title="Berlin Wall">Berlin Wall</a>, the <a href="/wiki/Trade_Expansion_Act" title="Trade Expansion Act">Trade Expansion Act</a> to
    lower tariffs, and the <a href="/wiki/African-American_Civil_Rights_Movement_(1955%E2%80%931968)" class="mw-redirect" title="African-American Civil Rights Movement (1955–1968)">Civil Rights Movement</a> all took place during his presidency. A member
    of the <a href="/wiki/Democratic_Party_(United_States)" title="Democratic Party (United States)">Democratic Party</a>, his <a href="/wiki/New_Frontier" title="New Frontier">New Frontier</a> domestic program was largely enacted as a memorial to him after
    his death.</p>

  <p>Kennedy's time in office was marked by high tensions with <a href="/wiki/Communist_states" class="mw-redirect" title="Communist states">Communist states</a>. Kennedy increased the number of American military advisers in <a href="/wiki/South_Vietnam" title="South Vietnam">South Vietnam</a> by
    a factor of 18 over Eisenhower. In <a href="/wiki/Cuba" title="Cuba">Cuba</a>, a failed attempt was made at the <a href="/wiki/Bay_of_Pigs" title="Bay of Pigs">Bay of Pigs</a> to overthrow the country's dictator <a href="/wiki/Fidel_Castro" title="Fidel Castro">Fidel Castro</a> in
    April 1961. Kennedy's administration subsequently rejected plans by the Joint Chiefs of Staff to <a href="/wiki/Operation_Northwoods" title="Operation Northwoods">orchestrate false-flag attacks on American soil in order to gain public approval for a war against Cuba</a>.
    In October 1962, it was discovered Soviet <a href="/wiki/Ballistic_missiles" class="mw-redirect" title="Ballistic missiles">ballistic missiles</a> had been deployed in Cuba; the resulting period of unease, termed the <a href="/wiki/Cuban_Missile_Crisis"
    title="Cuban Missile Crisis">Cuban Missile Crisis</a>, is seen by many historians as the closest the human race has ever come to <a href="/wiki/Nuclear_war" class="mw-redirect" title="Nuclear war">nuclear war</a> between nuclear armed belligerents.</p>
</div>
```